# Can we use multiple goals for maven build task in VSTS

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am new & exploring VSTS, I am working on a java application.
In Build task, I am using Maven job.
In maven tasks---> Goal(s) I want to give multiple goals for one single maven task. Is this possible? if I want to achieve multiple goals what I have to do? can someone help me with that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would just separate them by spaces in the usual Maven manner, like `clean install`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved this way by passing multiple parameters, also it can be used with parameters as well for test-related tasks:

goals: clean package test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/xmls/${{parameters.TestXMLs}}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yeah just use space
goals: 'clean install package'